# How to use GTest with CMake ? Linkage problem when following Google's guide

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, googletest

I started to use boost test for my project, but I need to mock static methods, so I try to switch to GTest and GMock.

I followed the really clear [guide](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project) from google, and the CMakeLists seems to be doing its job :

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(POC_V4)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)

# Specifying we are using pthread for UNIX systems.
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -Wall")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

# Package needed for Boost tests
find_package (Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework)
include_directories (${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

if(NOT Torch_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Pytorch Not Found!")
endif(NOT Torch_FOUND)

message(STATUS "Pytorch status :")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "    Torch Flags: ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

message(STATUS "OpenCV library status :")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")


# -------- GOOGLE TEST ----------
# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
enable_testing()
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
        RESULT_VARIABLE result
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
        RESULT_VARIABLE result
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()

# Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker
# settings on Windows
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

# Add googletest directly to our build. This defines
# the gtest and gtest_main targets.
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build
        EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

# The gtest/gtest_main targets carry header search path
# dependencies automatically when using CMake 2.8.11 or
# later. Otherwise we have to add them here ourselves.
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
    include_directories("${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
endif()
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Program executable
add_executable(POC_V4 src/main.cpp <all my other files>)

# Test executable
add_executable(POC_V4_tests test/main.cpp <all my other files>)

target_link_libraries(POC_V4 pthread dl util ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
target_link_libraries (POC_V4_tests gtest pthread dl util ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

**Output**

```sh
-- Pytorch status :
--     libraries: torch;torch_library;/usr/lib/libc10.so
--     Torch Flags: -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
-- OpenCV library status :
--     version: 4.2.0
--     libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_gapi;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_stitching;opencv_video;opencv_videoio
--     include path: /usr/local/include/opencv4
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/tmp.1U2MhnhFdi/cmake-build-debug-<projectName>_ubuntu/googletest-download
[ 11%] Performing update step for 'googletest'
Current branch master is up to date.
[ 22%] No configure step for 'googletest'
[ 33%] No build step for 'googletest'
[ 44%] No install step for 'googletest'
[ 55%] No test step for 'googletest'
[ 66%] Completed 'googletest'
[100%] Built target googletest
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/tmp.1U2MhnhFdi/cmake-build-debug-<projectName>_ubuntu
```

But when I'm compiling the `POC_V4_tests` target, I've got the following error

```sh
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/POC_V4_tests.dir/test/boxTest.cpp.o: in function `testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<int, int>(char const*, char const*, int const&, int const&)':
/tmp/tmp.1U2MhnhFdi/cmake-build-debug-<projectName>_ubuntu/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:1528: undefined reference to `testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, std::string const&, std::string const&, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm new to C++, so I may have missed something really simple. Can someone help me ?

**EDIT:**

I created an empty project, and it's working properly. I added the different dependencies, and found out that the problem comes from libtorch !

It is possible that libtorch defines some macros with the same names than GTest. I didn't find which one yet, but I hope I will be able to fix it with the [last part of google's tutorial](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest#avoiding-macro-name-clashes). If someone has an idea to find which macro is failing, it would help me a lot ! :D

Thanks to all people who tried to help me for now, I hope you will continue until we correct this !

Comment: On a side note: you can't mock static methods in gtest/gmock directly AFAIK. The method-to-be-mocked must be virtual, non-static method of a given class-to-be-mocked.

Comment: Oh.. So, do you know how I could mock Singleton classes in C++ ? If I can mock virtual methods, I could mock the methods called by my `getInstance()`, but I'm not sure it's a good practice... I found [this](https://helpercode.com/2015/09/16/how-to-fake-a-singleton-in-c/) tutorial that could fit my needs. But I need to make gtest work before :)

Comment: Maybe collision with `gtest` installed in your system and `gtest` that you download automatically? Check if you have gtest installed (e.g. `locate libgtest.so`). Check if your compiled libgtest.so (in your system and the one you download) has the required symbol `nm -D -C libgtest.so | grep EqFailure`. Compare the signature with what you have in your gtest headers.

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -Wall")` That's a red flag

Comment: You have not specified `PRIVATE | PUBLIC` specifier in your `target_link_libraries`

Comment: @pptaszni I already tried to uninstall the local version I've installed earlier. I've double checked the following symbols : `libgtest`, `libgtest.so`, `gtest`, `googletest`,  `google-test`, and nothing found. I manually checked my `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` folders,  and nothing again.

Comment: @Waqar What do you mean ?

Comment: @Waqar I've tried to link with both PRIVATE and PUBLIC tags, this doesn't change the error message.

Comment: I know, that was just a side note. And setting CXX_FLAGS globally  is never a good idea. Set them as required, per target.

Comment: And if all else fails, you can always create a subdir `googletest` and link to that. That will work.

Comment: Can you guide me to do this ? I'm new to CMake, I'ts a bit like black magic for me ^^'

Comment: I edited the post with new info, check it out !

Comment: I have the same problem with you and I try to `add_compile_definitions(_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)` in CMakeLists.txt. But it doesn't work and still reports same error. Is there other solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you share your error ? Is it exactly the same as me (libtorch + googletest link problem) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was not from GTest, but from libtorch, which is compiled with the CXX_ABI symbol. Just need to add `add_compile_definitions(_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)` on top of the CMakeLists and that will work.

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62693218/how-to-solve-gtest-and-libtorch-linkage-conflict) with a detailed answer.